# es6 import between files

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

fileA.js

```
import { bThing } from './fileB'
console.log(bThing)
export const aThing = 'aThing'
```

fileB.js

```
import { aThing } from './fileA'
console.log(aThing)
export const bThing = 'bThing'
```

The console.log in fileB outputs undefined. If I comment out the import in fileA then the import in fileB will work!

Comment: Is there a question or are you just pointing out how circular dependencies work?

Comment: Hint: If you did require the other file first, the `console.log` in fileA would output `undefined`.

Comment: In a real ES6 environment that would be a temporal deadzone error, but with Babel it's `undefined`

Comment: haha thanks for comments - it was a circular dependency of course - I thought nothing was impossible for webpack.